# Check JSON contents for specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, json.net

I've been learning and I think I'm finally at the end of this little "project" I've been struggling with! I've seen a few similar topics but can't quite adapt the code for my needs!

I have a JSON output that displays correctly, and I'm looking to search through it for a specific value, and only paste those results in the table.

I have the following Javascript that takes XML data and pastes it into a table.

Javascript

```
var html = '<table id="myTable"><thead><tr><th>Entry</th>';
    for ( row = 0; row < jsondata.rowCount; row++ )
    {
        html += "<tr><td>" + (row+1) + "</td>";
        for ( column = 0; column < jsondata.columnCount; column++ )
        {
            if((jsondata.xmlData [ row ] [ column ]) == "Ninja")
            {
                html += "<td>" + jsondata.xmlData [ row ] [ column ] + "</td>"
            }

            alert(jsondata.xmlData [ row ] [ column ]); //Added in edit - "undefined"
        }
        html += "</tbody></table>";
        $("#tablearea").html(html);
    }
```

EDIT: JSON

```
"xmlData" : [ [ "Ninja", "Blue"], [ "Car", "Red"] ]
```

If I exclude the if statement it will paste it all, but the if (when tested with an alert) states `undefined`.

Comment: Can you share a piece of your json data? Or even better, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: did you try to foreach or loop the json array to match the value?

Comment: Where do you put the alert? Please show it in your code.

Comment: @user3059001 - I have not, what's the syntax of such a loop? Finding the documentation tricky to say the least!

Comment: not really -- google javascript foreach -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: your json elements is inside jsonArray u can't use indexOf to match the seeking value or key u have to use `while(i < jsonarray.length ){ //match here i++;}` .. is that what u want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (MORE CONCISE):

I believe that your problem is that your rowCount member does not match your actual number of rows.  You could use the .length property of an array, or (in your given object), you could do the following...

```
var jsondata = {
    rowCount: 3,
    columnCount: 2,
    xmlData: [["Ninja", "Blue"], ["Car", "Red"]]
};

var html =  '<table id="myTable">' +
            '<thead>' +
            '<tr><th>Entry</th><tr>';
html += "<tbody>";
for (row = 0; row < jsondata.rowCount; row++) {
    var showRow = false;
    var tempHtml = "<tr>";
    for (column = 0; column < jsondata.columnCount; column++) {
        if (jsondata.xmlData[row]) {
            tempHtml += "<td>" + jsondata.xmlData[row][column] + "</td>";
            showRow = (jsondata.xmlData[row][column] == "Ninja") || showRow;
        }
    }
    tempHtml += "</tr>";
    if (showRow) {
        html += tempHtml;
    }
}
html += "</tbody></table>";
$("#tablearea").html(html);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However when working with an external JSON file it crashes! But I best try and figure that out on my own! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have rowCount and/or columCount not matching (maybe just switched) with the actual length of the arrays.

Anyway I'd suggest to retrieve the length of the arrays inspecting them directly

```
var html = '<table id="myTable"><thead><tr><th>Entry</th>';
for ( row = 0; row < jsondata.xmlData.length; row++ )
{
    html += "<tr><td>" + (row+1) + "</td>";
    for ( column = 0; column < jsondata.xmlData[row].length; column++ )
    {
        if((jsondata.xmlData [ row ] [ column ]) == "Ninja")
        {
            html += "<td>" + jsondata.xmlData [ row ] [ column ] + "</td>"
        }

    }
    html += "</tbody></table>";
    $("#tablearea").html(html);
}
```